# Weird behavior of zipped tensorflow dataset with random tensors

Tags: tensorflow, random, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

In the example below (Tensorflow 2.0), we have a dummy tensorflow dataset with three elements. We map a function on it (`replace_with_float`) that returns a randomly generated value in two copies. As we expect, when we take elements from the dataset, the first and second coordinates have the same value.

Now, we create two "slice" datasets from the first coordinates and the second coordinates, respectively and we zip the two datasets back together. The slicing and the zipping operations seems inverses of each other, so I would expect the resulting dataset to be equivalent to the previous one. However, as we see, now the first and second coordinates are different randomly generated values.

Maybe even more interestingly, if we zip the "same" dataset with itself by
`df = tf.data.Dataset.zip((df.map(lambda x, y: x), df.map(lambda x, y: x)))`, the two coordinates will also have different values.

How can this behavior be explained? Perhaps two different graphs are constructed for the two datasets to be zipped and they are run independently?

```
import tensorflow as tf

def replace_with_float(element):
    rand = tf.random.uniform([])
    return (rand, rand)

df = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0, 0, 0])
df = df.map(replace_with_float)
print('Before zipping: ')
for x in df:
    print(x[0].numpy(), x[1].numpy())

df = tf.data.Dataset.zip((df.map(lambda x, y: x), df.map(lambda x, y: y)))

print('After zipping: ')
for x in df:
    print(x[0].numpy(), x[1].numpy())
```

Sample output:

```
Before zipping: 
0.08801079 0.08801079
0.638958 0.638958
0.800568 0.800568
After zipping: 
0.9676769 0.23045003
0.91056764 0.6551999
0.4647777 0.6758332
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that datasets don't cache intermediate values between full iterations, unless you explicitly request that using `df.cache()`, and they don't deduplicate common inputs either.

So in the second loop, the entire pipeline runs again.
Similarly, in the second instance, the two `df.map` calls cause `df` to run twice.

Adding a `tf.print` helps explain what happens:

```
def replace_with_float(element):
    rand = tf.random.uniform([])
    tf.print('replacing', element, 'with', rand)
    return (rand, rand)
```

I've also pulled the lambdas on separate lines to avoid the autograph warning:

```
first = lambda x, y: x
second = lambda x, y: y

df = tf.data.Dataset.zip((df.map(first), df.map(second)))
```

```
Before zipping: 
replacing 0 with 0.624579549
0.62457955 0.62457955
replacing 0 with 0.471772075
0.47177207 0.47177207
replacing 0 with 0.394005418
0.39400542 0.39400542

After zipping: 
replacing 0 with 0.537954807
replacing 0 with 0.558757305
0.5379548 0.5587573
replacing 0 with 0.839109302
replacing 0 with 0.878996611
0.8391093 0.8789966
replacing 0 with 0.0165234804
replacing 0 with 0.534951568
0.01652348 0.53495157
```

To avoid the duplicate input problem, you can use use a single `map` call:

```
swap = lambda x, y: (y, x)
df = df.map(swap)
```

Or you can use `df = df.cache()` to avoid both effects:

```
df = df.map(replace_with_float)
df = df.cache()
```

```
Before zipping: 
replacing 0 with 0.728474379
0.7284744 0.7284744
replacing 0 with 0.419658661
0.41965866 0.41965866
replacing 0 with 0.911524653
0.91152465 0.91152465

After zipping: 
0.7284744 0.7284744
0.41965866 0.41965866
0.91152465 0.91152465
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what happens, but this behavior still seems counterintuitive to me. Can you even produce such behavior in TF 1.x? Calling session.run once with a single graph would give the same random number for the two cases. Calling two session.runs for the two branches would give different numbers, but the two calls would take different inputs from the initial dataset (I believe). What happens under the hood here?

Comment: Yes, I agree it's counterintuitive, and has performance implications as well - I think it's worth filing a bug about this. I think tf.data pipelines should de-duplicate earlier stages so that they're not being executed twice.